# QRunnable with setAutoDelete(False) leads to memory leak in PySide6

Tags: multithreading, pyside6, qrunnable

We have a `Task` class, inherited from `QRunnable` to run it's code in a separate thread.
When `task.setAutoDelete(True)` (which is the default value), then everything works well: task is deleted after `run()` is finished.
But we need to keep the task in memory some time to display it's status: so we need to keep a reference to it.
So we set `task.setAutoDelete(False)`: then `QThreadPool` will not delete it.
And we expect, that task will be deleted (by garbage collector), when all our references to it are gone. But the task is not deleted even when `gc.collect()` is called, and even when program is closed.

1. Is it a memory leak, when `task.setAutoDelete(False)`?
2. When `task.setAutoDelete(True)`: should the `QThreadPool` delete C++ object of `QRunnable` or python wrapper of `QRunnable`?

The code to reproduce the problem (it **does not keep** the reference on task to be more concise):

```
import gc
import sys
import time

from PySide6.QtCore import QRunnable, QThreadPool
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout


class Task(QRunnable):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def __del__(self):
        print('Task.__del__')

    def run(self):
        print('Task.run')
        time.sleep(3)  # other long working function was tested too with no difference
        print(f'Task.run finished')


def run_task():
    task = Task()
    task.setAutoDelete(False)  # without this line the task object is deleted
    QThreadPool().globalInstance().start(task)


def collect_by_gc():
    collected_count = gc.collect()
    print(f'collected by GC: {collected_count}')


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    run_task_push_button = QPushButton('Run Task')
    run_task_push_button.clicked.connect(run_task)

    collect_by_gc_push_button = QPushButton('Collect by GC')
    collect_by_gc_push_button.clicked.connect(collect_by_gc)

    layout = QVBoxLayout()
    layout.addWidget(run_task_push_button)
    layout.addWidget(collect_by_gc_push_button)

    window = QWidget()
    window.setWindowTitle('Test App')
    window.setLayout(layout)
    window.show()

    app.exec()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If `Run Task` button is pressed, the output is:

```
Task.run
Task.run finished

Process finished with exit code 0
```

(the destructor of task was not called. And even is not called, when `Collect by GC` button is pressed. We expected it to be called.)

But when `task.setAutoDelete(True)` then everything works well and destructor is called. The output is:

```
Task.run
Task.run finished
Task.__del__

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Improved code example to **keep** the reference on task:

```
import gc
import sys
import time

from PySide6.QtCore import QRunnable, QThreadPool, QObject, Signal
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout

# from PyQt6.QtCore import QRunnable, QThreadPool, pyqtSignal, QObject, Qt
# from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout


class TaskSignals(QObject):
    # finished = pyqtSignal()
    finished = Signal()


class Task(QRunnable):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.signals = TaskSignals()

    def __del__(self):
        print('Task.__del__')

    def run(self):
        print('Task.run')
        time.sleep(2)  # other long working function was tested too with no difference
        print(f'Task.run finished')
        self.signals.finished.emit()


class MainWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self._run_task_button = QPushButton('Run Task')
        self._run_task_button.clicked.connect(self._run_task)

        collect_by_gc_button = QPushButton('Collect by GC')
        collect_by_gc_button.clicked.connect(self._collect_by_gc)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self._run_task_button)
        layout.addWidget(collect_by_gc_button)

        self.setWindowTitle('Test App')
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self._task = None

    def _run_task(self):
        self._run_task_button.setDisabled(True)

        self._task = Task()
        self._task.setAutoDelete(False)  # without this line the task object is deleted
        self._task.signals.finished.connect(self._on_task_finished)
        QThreadPool().globalInstance().start(self._task)

    @staticmethod
    def _collect_by_gc():
        collected_count = gc.collect()
        print(f'collected by GC: {collected_count}')

    def _on_task_finished(self):
        print(f'MainWidget._on_task_finished')
        self._task.signals.finished.disconnect(self._on_task_finished)
        self._task = None
        self._run_task_button.setEnabled(True)


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    window = MainWidget()
    window.show()

    app.exec()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

That improved example dumps expected output with PyQt 6.6.1 (when autoDelete is any (False or True)):

```
Task.run
Task.run finished
MainWidget._on_task_finished
Task.__del__

Process finished with exit code 0
```

But with PySide 6.6.2 it dumps the same expected output only if autoDelete is True. When autoDelete is False the `__del__` is not dumped.

Tested on Windows 10 (x64), Python 3.10.12, PySide 6.6.2 and PySide 6.5.2. Thanks!

Comment: Note that `__del__` is *not* a destructor (the Python docs also state it's an improper definition): it will *probably* only be called as soon as the reference count reaches zero. There's also no guarantee that `__del__` will always be called, especially when dealing with complex situations and object wrappers, as it happens with bindings like PySide/PyQt. Qt also has absolutely no knowledge about Python, so QThreadPool just destroys the C++ object when `autoDelete` is `True`. You may consider keeping a reference to `Task` and then use [`tryTake()`](//doc.qt.io/qt-6/qthreadpool.html#tryTake)

Comment: @musicamante The [docs state](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthreadpool.html#start) that the thread pool explictly ***won't*** take ownership when auto-delete is false, so the PySide behaviour looks dubious. If you look at the OP's `run_task` function, it does not keep a Python reference. I would therefore expect no output from the virtual `run` method (because the task was immediately garbage-collected) and/or a seg-fault (because Qt tried to access an object that no longer exists). This implies `__del__` should be diagnostic. With PyQt6, the code calls `__del__` and dumps core exactly as expected.

Comment: The example *does* seem to demonstrate a memory leak. The code itself makes no attempt to keep a reference to the task, so PySide must be doing that by itself when it really shouldn't. When setting auto-delete to false, you ***must*** keep a reference to the runnable on the Python side and then explicitly delete it yourself at the appropriate time.

Comment: @ekhumoro I also thought that the behavior is not expected (I forgot to mention that), and probably PySide keeps a reference for some reason: whatever that may be, though, it seems invalid and inconsistent.

Comment: @ekhumoro @musicamante Thanks for your comments! In our real code, we are **keeping** the Python reference on the Task object. The code to reproduce problem does **not keep** the reference to be more concise. I have edited the post: added code example, where we are keeping task reference some time. Like @ekhumoro, I have tested new code example with PyQt 6.6.1, and `__del__` dumps as expected too. I plan to write bug report for PySide team.

Comment: Filled the bug report here: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-2621